# HTTP REST refused from phone but not from emulator

Tags: android, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

My android app does POSTs to my ASP NET WEB API service running at my public website.  It works great when testing on the AVD emulator.  But when I test on my Android Phone I get...

"Connection to http://www.deanblakely.com refused"

My post code is pasted below
Thanks, Gary

```
private String PostToCloudService(URL url, String entityString)
{
    String retstr = "";
    try
    {
        Log.w(getClass().getName(), "copy this: " + entityString );
        Log.w(getClass().getName(), "URL is: " + url );
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams,5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 5000);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);

        HttpPost myPost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(entityString);
        myPost.setEntity(se);
        myPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        myPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        response = httpclient.execute(myPost);    

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Log.w(getClass().getName(), "response from getentity is " + line);
            retstr = line;
        }        
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.w(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage().toString());
        retstr = "error  " + e.getMessage().toString();
    }

    return retstr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It works great when testing on the AVD emulator. But when I test on my Android Phone I get...
>
> "Connection to http://www.deanblakely.com refused"

I've had similar issues in the past, and they have all come down environment configuration. I expect that your computer running the emulator is connected to an internal network and the device is not.

If this is indeed the case, then it's most likely setup on the service that you are attempting to communicate with. I would expect if a service is currently in development or limited for some other reason that they would only allow internal connection.